# change macports installation makefile

Tags: opencv, macports

how can I change the `cmake` file provided with the package? I am having troubles with `OpenCV` and found one possible solution:

So you can edit cmake/OpenCVDetectionVTK.cmake.
At line 6, change "vtkRenderingOpenGL" to "vtkRenderingOpenGL2".

But where do I change that if I am using `port install`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look on directory up (out of directory build whether you create it) you will see the "cmake/"

Mine is look like this:

3rdparty        CONTRIBUTING.md README.md       build           data            include         platforms
CMakeLists.txt  LICENSE         apps            cmake           doc             modules         samples

Open cmake then you will find it.

I hope this help you.